# Apple TV "See" series - are the knots a real form of communication?

Tags: plot-explanation, realism, see

In the Apple TV Series "See", are the strings they read real? I think the last episode or 2 I heard them called knots.

Just curious if it's a real way of communications or made up. Doesn't look like they use [Braille](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braille) much in the series. Searching Google has been difficult because of the series name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it's based on a real mode of 'writing' used by the Incas, known as [Quipu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quipu) or khipu.

[image]

<sup>©The Trustees of the British Museum</sup>

There was an article I remembered reading in the New Scientist a few years ago about it - managed to find the online version…
[**We thought the Incas couldn't write. These knots change everything**](https://www.newscientist.com/article/mg23931972-600-we-thought-the-incas-couldnt-write-these-knots-change-everything/)
A lost language encoded in intricate cords is finally revealing its secrets – and it could upend what we know about Incan history and culture

Comment: beat me by a minute hahaha

Comment: Learned about khipu from a Clive Cussler novel of all places.

Comment: Strange. I remember reading about native Americans/First Nations recording messages with knotted rope/string when I was a boy in the 1980s. Maybe they knew it was a language but didn’t know how to translate it, and New Scientist just implied otherwise to up the drama a tick.

Comment: @ToddWilcox For a very long time we thought the knots only recorded numbers - similar to Akkadian shipping logs/accounting tablets in cuneiform. It's only in the last 5 years or so that we have started deciphering non-numeric knots.

Comment: fun kid fact : Quipu would means 'who smell' in French. Yes it's irrelevant.